# Spotify cache now at 11gb, how to delete with Crontab?

Tags: cron, spotify

I am aware that Spotify downloads songs and keeps them on my hard disk rather than keep re-streaming them.  However, my Spotify cache is now up to 11gb and I’d like to use crontab to delete it.

I found this post here from 2018:  [Why is the Spotify cache so large?](https://superuser.com/questions/1285024/why-is-the-spotify-cache-so-large) and used the commands within in crontab to schedule it to delete but it no longer works.

Has something changed since this original post meaning I need to use a different command in macOS Catalina?

Comment: `... it no longer works.` How does it not work? Errors? Crash? Deletion of other folders?

Comment: Have you tried running `rm "Library/Caches/com.spotify.client"` manually? What about changing it to `rm -f "Library/Caches/com.spotify.client"`? Or heck, what about looking for the file yourself by running a simple `ls -la Library/Caches/` and see if there is a Spotify file there?

Comment: The cron job doesn't delete anything @SaaruLindestøkke

Comment: All of those commands just return "is a directory" @JakeGould

Comment: Try `rm -rf "Library/Caches/com.spotify.client` and see what happens. If it’s a directory you need the `-r` flag to tell `rm` to be recursive for directory deletions.

Comment: Thanks for this @JakeGould. I am trying this command just from Terminal, not using Cron.  This command appears to run without any problems, but the directory still remains and isn't deleted.  How strange?

Comment: When i run ls -la Library/Caches/ i can see the folder, and next to it it has what i believe are the read write permissions.  It shows "drwx------" where as all the other folders show "drwxr-xr-x".  Is this possibly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On MmacOS Catalina the `com.spotify.client` cache folder lives in `~/Library/Caches`:

```
$ ls -lah ~/Library/Caches | grep com.spotify
drwx------    8 sl  staff   256B Jul 17 17:04 com.spotify.client
drwxr-xr-x    5 sl  staff   160B Mar 23 09:50 com.spotify.client.helper
drwxr-xr-x    5 sl  staff   160B Mar  6 19:24 com.spotify.installer
```

As you already saw, the `com.spotify.client` folder has **r**ead, **w**rite and e**x**ecute permissions for the owner of the file (in this case `sl`).
Users in the group (in this case `staff`) and other users have no permissions.

As you are (most likely) the owner of that folder you should be able to delete it.

To delete that folder once you would write in terminal:

```
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.spotify.client
```

The `-r` flag recurses through the directory and is needed to delete folders.

If you want to run this command periodically you can refer to [earlier questions on that subject](https://superuser.com/q/126907/141595).